# Predicate logic definable sets question

Tags: logic

Let L = L0 ∨ {R} where L0 is the basic language with equality and R is a binary relation symbol. Consider the L-structure X which has underlying set X = {a, b, c, d, e} and where
RX ={(a,b),(b,b),(b,c),(c,b),(c,d),(d,a),(e,c),(e,e)}.
(1) Draw the directed graph of X .
(2) Determine the sets φ(X), ψ(X) and ρ(X) where

φ(x) = ∃y (R(y, x) ∧ R(x, y)),
ψ(x) = ∃y (R(y, x) → R(x, x)) and
ρ(x) = ∀y (R(y, x) → R(y, y)).

Obviously the drawing of the digraph is fine, I'm just struggling with the interpretation of the sets, in particular the 2nd, which I thought would be {b,e} but I know because of the definition of implication this may not be the case. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a given predicate $\kappa(x)$, the set $\kappa(X)$ is constructed of elements in $X$ where the predicate is true.    $\kappa(X) := \{x\in X: \kappa(x)\}$

We have been given the set $X:=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and relation $R:=\{(a,b),(b,b),(b,c),(c,b),(c,d),(d,a),(e,c),(e,e)\}$

---

$\phi(x) = \exists y(R(x,y)\wedge R(y,x))$.

For any $x$ we require one example.   Because $(x,x)$ will do, if available, then we know $\{b,e\}\subseteq \phi(X)$.

For the other three elements determine which, if any, occur in symmetric pairs; eg: $(b,c)\wedge (c,b)$.

---

$\psi (x) = \exists y (R(y, x) \to R(x, x))$

Because $R(x,x)\to R(x,x)$ is a tautology, therefore immediately we infer $\psi(X)=X$.

---

$\rho(x) ~=~ \forall y~(R(y,x)\to R(y,y)) ~=~ \neg \exists y~(R(y,x)\wedge\neg R(y,y))$

If we can find any such counter example we can exclude the element from being in the set $\rho(X)$.

So $a\notin \rho(X)$ , because $R(d,a)\wedge\neg R(d,d)$, however $c\in \rho(X)$, because $\neg \exists y~(R(y,c)\wedge\neg R(y,y))$, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to think about whether $\psi(x)$ holds for each element one by one. First see if $\psi(a)$ is true. It would be true if there is some y such that $R(y, a) \rightarrow R(a, a)$. Since $R(a, a)$ is not true, that implication is only true when $R(y, a)$ is false. So let $y = b$< and then you can see that $R(b, a) \rightarrow R(a, a)$ is true, therefore there is such a $y$ that makes that sentence true.

Similarly, check whether $\psi(x)$ holds for each of $b, c, d,$ and $e$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, the 2nd case would hold for the entire set because we can always choose a suitable y to make the implication true? And how would this compare with the case "for all y" instead of "there exists y", for example in the 3rd with rho(x)?

Comment: Yes, since for each $x$, either $R(x, x)$ holds or there is some $y$ such that $R(y, x$ does not. In the third case, let $x = b$, and think about whether it's true that, for every $y$, $R(y, b) \rightarrow R(y, y)$. You have to check all possible values for $y$ here, and if all of them make that implication true, then $\rho(b)$ is true also.

Comment: So as the implication is false when R(a,b) --> R(a,a) rho(b) does not hold? Similar for the others hence rho(x)={c,e}?

Comment: That looks right.